# Passing a Boolean from Azure Datafactory to Azure Databricks activity as a parameter

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a pipeline configured in Datafactory. It has a activity that calls a Databricks notebook.
I want to pass a Boolean from Datafactory and read it into Databricks notebook so I can use it to execute condition based on Boolean value.
I passed a string type of parameter with value 'False' from Datafactory and convert it to a bool.
test_var = bool(dbutils.widgets.get("bool_var"))
If i print test_var, it prints as True even if I pass False.

How to resolve this?

I tried converting the string to bool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `bool(dbutils.widgets.get("bool_var"))`, it will always evaluate to `True` because the string is not empty

To resolve this, you can explicitly check the string value and convert it to a Boolean accordingly

```
bool_var_str = dbutils.widgets.get("bool_var")

# Convert the string to a Boolean
test_var = bool_var_str.lower() == 'true'
```

This snippet explicitly checks if the lowercase version of the string is `true`, ensuring a proper conversion to a Boolean. Make sure to pass `False` from DataFactory when you want the Boolean variable to be `False`, and `True` when you want it to be `True`